# EF Core Treating Entities the Same But One Is Null and One Is Not

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

Alright, y'all. I've been staring at this for hours, I feel like I'm losing my mind. I know this is a bit, and I'm sorry it's so long, I tried to make it flow as easily as possible, but uhhh.... let me just put the tl;dr up front.

tl;dr: Treating two objects ("entities" in EF Core) the same, but for some reason they're being treated differently and giving me a very annoying error. What gives?

Okay, first I'm using Entity Framework 6.4.4, EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.4, Visual Studio 16.10.0, and .NET Core 3.1, but, for reasons you'll see later, I don't really think that's relevant here. I'm just including that to get it out of the way.

So, this is going to be a bit, but I'll try to keep it as simple as possible. I'm having trouble with data access, and I can't figure out why. Let me start with my models. I'm going to include three (and simplify them)

MyNamespace/Models/Project.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        // Bunch of other stuff, doesn't matter

        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MyNamespace.Models.File> Files { get; set; }
        // Yes I'm intentionally using the full path here because this is where the confusion is
    }
}
```

MyNamespace/Models/Comment.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class Comment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        // Other attributes

        public Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyNamespace/Models/File.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class File
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        // Other attributes

        public MyNamespace.Models.Project Project { get; set; }
        // Again being very explicit here because I'm at a loss
    }
}
```

You see what I got here, right? A `Project` entity can contain zero or many comments and zero or many files, and each comment or file can be associated with one project. It's a one-to-many relationship we're looking at. Not super complicated, I have other entities with similar relationships, everything works like I expect it to, except the `File` entity. I'm including the `Comment` entity here to illustrate that, so far as I can tell, I'm treating the `File` entity properly, same as the `Comment` entity, but I don't know why it's not working. Just so you know, though, there are other entities that I'm also treating the same and are also working fine.

So those are the models in question. Here's my `DbContext`

MyNamespace/Data/ProjectDBContext.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Data
{
    public class ProjectDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        // Other stuff

        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MyNamespace.Models.File> Files { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Again, I have plenty of stuff in there, everything was working as expected until I added this new `File` model.

So, now that we've set everything up, let's get into the code.

My organization is a little weird ,I know, (but I think it's kind of proper?), but I'm going to include all of it that I believe is relevant. I'm using View Components and Razor Pages, so, first, we have a regular Razor page (I'll include the `MyNamespace/Pages/Projects/View.cshtml.cs` if you all really want it, but I really don't think the problem is here, so I'm going to skip it for now.)

MyNamepsace/Pages/Projects/View.cshtml

```
@model MyNamespace.Pages.Projects.View

<!-- Some stuff -->

<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("CommentsBox", Model.Project)
</div>

<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("FilesBox", Model.Project)
</div>

<!-- Other stuff -->
```

Now, I want to be clear, the `Files` stuff doesn't work. The `Comments` stuff does. I'm including both to illustrate that it works with one and not the other, and I don't know why. Sorry, so, the first part of our view components.

MyNamespace/ViewComponents/CommentsBox.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.ViewComponents
{
    public class CommentsBox : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(Project project)
        {
            return View("Default", project)
        }
    }
}
```

MyNamespace/ViewComponents/FilesBox.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.ViewComponents
{
    public class FilesBox : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(Project project)
        {
            // We'll come back to this later, but I have a breakpoint set at this line.
            return View("Default", project)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the views (I actually don't know if I'm using the correct parlance when I call these "the views" but that's not the point here)

MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/CommentsBox/Default.cshtml

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.Project

<!-- Some stuff -->

@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    // Just display info, this all works fine
}

<!-- Some stuff -->
```

MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.Project

<!-- Some stuff -->

@foreach (var file in Model.Files) // ERROR
{
    // Supposed to display the info
}

<!-- Some stuff -->

<!-- Do note, there is some code here to upload a file. If I remove the code above that's throwing the error, It actually does upload the file. -->
```

So the error I'm getting is complaining about the `for` loop in `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml`, it's an `ArgumentNullException`. It's complaining that `Model.Files` is null, so I can't iterate over it. But this doesn't make sense, (well you'll see it does a little bit, but I don't know why it's `null`). Because, for a project where I have no comments and no files, the loop in `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/CommentsBox/Default.cshtml` works just fine. Why does it work for `Comments` and not `Files`?

Further, if I remove the for loop from `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml` and use the code that uploads a file to upload a file, it works just fine. No problem at all. Now, we know we have a file in the database associated with this project. So, just for funsies, let's change `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml`

MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.Project

<!-- Some stuff -->

@try
{
    @foreach (var file in Model.Files)
    {
        // We should display info here
    }
}
catch (Exception ArgumentNullException)
{
    <text>Woops we've caught our exception</text>
}

<!-- Some stuff -->

<!-- Do note, there is some code here to upload a file. It actually does upload the file, if I remove the code above that's throwing the error -->
```

Okay, so we know we have a file in the database, I can see it in the database (not on the webpage ) and I can see that its `ProjectID` is exactly what I expect it to be. Running it again, we catch our error condition. Why? We know we have a file in the database with a `ProjectID` pointing to our project. Remember, we don't have this problem with comments. Even if there are no comments in the database with this `ProjectID`, we don't get this error. Yet, even when we DO have a file in the database, we're still getting the error and we can even confirm by asking for the error condition.

Okay, so, we know we have a file in the database pointing to our project, yet we're still entering the error condition. I change `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml` back to the original, without the error checking. Database retains its information, no worries there. But we're back to the same error. It's just not associating the `File` entity with its proper `Project` entity.

Remember that breakpoint? This is where things get curious. If I inspect the `Project` object that's being passed from `MyNamepsace/Pages/Projects/View.cshtml` to `MyNamespace/ViewComponents/FilesBox.cs` to `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml` at `MyNamespace/ViewComponents/FilesBox.cs` right before it goes to `MyNamespace/Pages/Shared/FilesBox/Default.cshtml`, I see something interesting. We can inspect the object during that moment in runtime and see that indeed, the `Files` attribute of our `Project` object is `null`, but for `Comments`? It's not `null`, it's `Count = 0`... so... why? I feel like I did the exact same thing for both of them. I set them up the same way, treated them the same in the `DbContext`, treated them the same in their models, and their association with `Project`. Why is one being treated differently?

Further, if we inspect the `Project` object at that breakpoint, we can see that for its `Comments` attribute, where, again, the value is `Count = 0`, the type is `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyNamespace.Models.Comment> {System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<MyNamespace.Models.Comment>}`. For the `Files` attribute of our `Project` object, however, where the value is `null` (even though we know there's files in the database with a `ProjectID` pointing to this project), the type is just `System.Collection.Generic.ICollection<MyNamespace.Models.File>`. I even tried changing the model `MyNamespace/Models/Project.cs` to

MyNamespace/Models/Project.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        // Bunch of other stuff, doesn't matter

        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public HashSet<MyNamespace.Models.File> Files { get; set; }
        // See? I'm specifying the HashSet type here
    }
}
```

but, to no avail. Same error, same behavior.

I'm sure whatever I'm missing is small, but I've been looking at this for, by the time I typed this whole thing up, more than a day now, and I'm just at a loss. Is it a Visual Studio thing? Am I missing something? I just don't know. I'm hoping you fine folks might be either able to see what I don't, or might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Woweeeee. Remember how I said, "I'll include the `MyNamespace/Pages/Projects/View.cshtml.cs` if you all really want it, but I really don't think the problem is here, so I'm going to skip it for now"?

Well I should have included it. Woe betide the fool who doesn't track down her object. Here's the relevant code from `MyNamespace/Pages/Projects/View.cshtml.cs`

MyNamespace/Pages/Projects/View.cshtml.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Pages.Projects
{
    public class View : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IReposity _reposity;

        public Project Project { get; set; }

        public View (IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            // Some stuff

            Project = _repository.GetOneProjectByIDAsNoTrackingAsync(id);

            // Some other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So, you see, I'm using a repository for my data access, so let's look at the relevant method in that repository. *sigh*

MyNamespace/Repositories/Repository.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Repositories
{
    private ProjectDBContext _context;

    public Repository(ProjectDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Project> GetOneProjectByIDAsNoTrackingAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Projects
            .Include(p => p.Comments)
            .Inlcude(p => p.SomethingElse)
            // Include a bunch of other stuff
            .ThenInclude(s => s.SomethingElseChild)
            .AsNotracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
    }
}
```

You see, I never included my `File` entity here. Yikes, right? It should be

MyNamespace/Repositories/Repository.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Repositories
{
    private ProjectDBContext _context;

    public Repository(ProjectDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Project> GetOneProjectByIDAsNoTrackingAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Projects
            .Include(p => p.Comments)
            .Inlcude(p => p.SomethingElse)
            .Include(p => p.Files) // <== THIS THIS THIS
            // Include a bunch of other stuff
            .ThenInclude(s => s.SomethingElseChild)
            .AsNotracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
    }
}
```

I wrote that whole 1,500 word question only to realize what I was missing. Anyway, I'm leaving it there and answering this question for posterity.